# How to limit `\lastpageref` to current/local pagination scheme when using multiple schemes (of the same type) with `pageslts`?

Tags: page-numbering

I'm working on a document that uses `\pagenumbering{roman}` for the frontmatter, `\pagenumbering{arabic}` for the mainmatter, and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` again (restarted from 1) for the backmatter. I am trying to put "N of M" in the footer using the `pageslts` package, but I can't figure out how to restrict M to the local pagination scheme.

I get the desired outcome if I use `\rfoot{\theCurrentPageLocal~of~\lastpageref*{pagesLTS.arabic.1}}` for the mainmatter and then change to `\rfoot{\theCurrentPageLocal~of~\lastpageref*{pagesLTS.arabic.2}}` for the backmatter. However, I would like to give a global definition in the preamble so I don't have to redefine (and keep track of order) each time.

I thought `\rfoot{\thepage~of~\lastpageref*{pagesLTS.arabic.local}}` should do the trick but it returns the last page of only the last scheme rather than the local scheme. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pagecontinue=false]{pageslts}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{\theCurrentPageLocal~of~\lastpageref*{pagesLTS.arabic.local}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\section{Frontmatter}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Mainmatter}
\lipsum[2-5]

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman} % forces reset of lastpageref counter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Backmatter}
\lipsum[6-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't get `pagecontinue=false` to work at all. I get tons of warnings telling me numbers will not be continued... but then they are anyway. Apparently, I fundamentally fail to grasp almost everything the documentation says.

Comment: I guess `pagecontinue=false` isn't necessary if `\setcounter{page}{1}` is there. I feel like I'll need it for a nice, global solution, though.

Comment: True but it leaves me with little confidence that I have any understanding of the package whatsoever since it seems like a fairly simple option. (If I don't understand even *that*, what hope?!)

Comment: That's more or less how I feel.

Comment: As far as i can tell, the `local` label is an internal macro only. But why is there a setcounter followed by two `\pagenumbering` commands? Why having arabic numbering twice? Though it is possible, it is confusing for the reader.

Comment: @Johannes_B I agree about it being confusing. But it still leaves the question of what `pagecontinue=false` does or is supposed to do...

Comment: @cfr The opposite of true, it resets the pagecounter if the same nubmering scheme is used again. In contrast to ...

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagecontinue=true]{pageslts}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\lipsum[1-17]
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[1-17]
\pagenumbering{roman}
\lipsum[1-17]
\end{document}
`

Comment: Or try: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagecontinue=false]{pageslts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{\theCurrentPageLocal~of~\lastpageref*{pagesLTS.arabic.local}}
\lfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\lipsum[1-17]
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[1-27]
\pagenumbering{roman}
\lipsum[1-17]
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Johannes_B It seems the two `\pagenumbering` commands are necessary to restart the arabic numbering when using `[pagecontinue=false]`. Without changing from arabic to something else (roman, in this case) the arabic isn't recognized as a new scheme. Of course this is not ideal, but I was hoping this would allow me to use `\theCurrentPageLocal` and some kind of `\lastpageref` to obtain N of M for the two separate numbering schemes.

Comment: @erik Jep, that's true, you need switch to a different numbering scheme first. But the setcounter can be omitted ;-) But to be honest, i was quite confused by the different numbering schemes and never knew, what i should expect. There was something odd, i just don't know if this is a feature, a bug, by design, or just not doable. Sorry.

Comment: @Johannes_B Hmmm... I don't really understand it. And I don't understand how what it does relates to the documentation. Why does `\lastpageref*{pagesLTS.arabic.local}` end up being `7` and why isn't `theCurrentPageLocal` the local page number, even with `pagecontinue=false`?